# Android layout templates?

Tags: android

are there any sources of templates for layouts?

I need some typical layouts to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there are. Checkout the [Hello Views](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/index.html) section and of course the [API Demos](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/get.html).

Alternatively as Android is opensource you can checkout the [sources](http://android.git.kernel.org/) or just [clone](http://source.android.com/source/download.html) the git repo.